# how to display Stackoverflow Question in your flask website

Tags: api, flask, atom-editor

I am looking for the best way to show a list of Stackoverflow question on my website. My website uses flask for python.

I have found a library called py-stackexchange 2.2.7. I am using this question to test implementing this solution. However, I would love a simple way to allow my users to search for questions related to a keyword on my site.

Users will log in to my app and create their project. next, they will list code they dont understand when they research their project design. Lastly, I want to have a season of the "project research page" to have a list of similar Stack overview Question.....like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after testing py-stackexchange, I got it to work. I'm still looking for a better way that I can scale per topic and per user in a multi-tenet application.

```
so = stackexchange.Site(stackexchange.StackOverflow)
me = so.user(**<yourstackoverflow_user_id>**)

qs= me.questions.fetch()

#print("Test 2: ",qs)
#pass **[ANSWER]**
#print("Test 3: ",qs.pagesize)
#pass
# qs = qs.extend_next()
#print("Test 4: ",qs)
#fail
#print("Test 5: ", qs.extend_next())
#fail '
```